# integrating OSM in android

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am new to android and as the first step of my application, I want to load up OSM map.

I am having errors while adding OSM jar files to my application. 
I have added the following code to my **build.gradle(Module:app)** file as suggested on https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle.

```
     compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.1@aar'
```

I have also downloaded and put the following files in **app/libs** folder.

1. osmdroid-android-5.1.aar
2. osmdroid-android-5.1-javadoc
3. osmdroid-android-5.1-sources

When I run the application, I am getting the following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>
> ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/osmdroid/ic_menu_mapmode.png
>       File1: C:\Users\heinm\AndroidStudioProjects\OSMTest\app\libs\osmdroid-android-5.1-sources.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\heinm\AndroidStudioProjects\OSMTest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\org.osmdroid\osmdroid-android\5.1\jars\classes.jar

I would really appreciate if someone could point out what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to remove the `osmdroid-android-5.1-sources` file from the `app/libs` folder.

Comment: @Titus Cheers mate. It solves the problem. Thank you very much, I have been searching all over the place how to solve it. You saved me a lot of time. Really appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, good luck.